# Very big file in /var/logs/syslog due to repeating error

Tags: system, root

I got a notification that that my root directory was running out of space which was odd because I had given it 20 GB of space and the installation was only a day old. After a bit of snooping, the offending file was `/var/logs/syslog`. After looking at the `tail` of the syslog, it seems to just be this error message repeated many times.

`Feb  6 01:45:08 matebook io.elementary.cerbere.desktop[1715]: [0206/014508.524217:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(316)] Failed to recv from netlink socket: Permission denied (13)`

Any idea what the cause of this log is and how to stop it from generating hundreds of logs per second? Tried googling the error but can't seem to find anyone else with the same error message